# How i can add babel in webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, babeljs, webpacker

I am writing frontend and for the first time I needed to connect babel in a RoR application using webpacker. I don’t understand what I should interact with to realize this.

I downloaded the necessary packages for babel: 
-babel-code-frame; 
-babel-loader; 
-babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node; 
-babel-plugin-macros.

Then I tried to interact with `webpacker.yml` and files from `config/webpack/*.js.` Nothing came of it.

on backend we use ruby 2.5.1 and rails 6.0.0.rc2v

this is `config/webpack/development.js` file:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const webpack = require('webpack');
const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

enviroment.js file:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('ProvidePlugin', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
}))

module.exports = environment
```

and production.js file:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

webpacker.yml file:

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules

  compile: false

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2
    - .mp3
    - .ogg

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .js.erb
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  extract_css: false

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```